# Get the length of a deserialized object array

Tags: json, vb.net

I've got following object structure from a JSON deserialization. Then, I can access properly to its values, but how can I get the length of an `Object` array using a specific key?
I need to get length shown in the picture like `jsonDes("result").length`.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show yor complete code as text?

Comment: Ab object does not have a length like a string does.  What Intellisense is showing that the size of an object *array*. `jsonDes.result("result")` specifically.  I'd be concerned that a complex object like that is not Typed.

Comment: @Plutonix, that is exactly what I need, the size of the object array (so =10 in the example)

Comment: well, as before `jsonDes.result("result").Length` should give the answer.  The problem is that the first object (`jsonDes.result`) appears to be a dictionary cast as `Object` so you will have trouble drilling into it *as* a dictionary.  I guess you could try casting, but it would be better to deserialize it to Type

Comment: downvote? please explain why

Comment: Could you include some more code? For example the structure of the object you're deserializing, how and to what you deserialize it.

Comment: @Plutonix thank you, It worked, However, Visual Studio help doesn't have .length suggestion... That is why I was trying to look for another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will just print the expected result using VB.NET dynamic features:

```
Dim jsonDes As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(...)
Dim length As Integer = jsonDes("result").length
Console.WriteLine(length)
```